# Unable to align two div's vertically in one line

Tags: html, css

I am having two divs. One text box and another a button. I am unable to align both divs vertically. I need the text box and button to be of equal height and vertically aligned in same line. What is wrong?

```css
.inputHolder{
  border:1px solid #FFF;
 vertical-align:middle;
}
.input{
 margin-top:150px;
 width:100px;
 height:50px;
 border:1px solid black;
 font-size:1.2em;
 padding:5px;
 display:inline-block;
}
.input:focus{
 outline:0;
}
.goBtn{
 height:50px;
 width:200px;
 border:1px solid black;
 display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <div class="inputHolder">
   <input type="text" class="input">
   <input type="submit" value="Go" class="goBtn">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Display `flex` on the parent will make them the same height and side-by-side

```css
.inputHolder {
  border: 1px solid #FFF;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.input {
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  padding: 5px;
}

.input:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.goBtn {
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="inputHolder">
  <input type="text" class="input">
  <input type="submit" value="Go" class="goBtn">
</div>
```

Comment: sadly display:flex is not compatible with all browsers

Comment: @TriForce it has 97.71% global browser support, and OP didn't list a particular browser that doesn't support flexbox as a requirement in their post.

Comment: But the problem is that it is aligned to left side of the screen and i am unable to center it

Comment: lot of users are still using windows 7, so theres a high percentage of users which never updated their browsers or download new ones (im talking about IE8 9 and 10). flex is only compatible with IE11. but np, is just a comment...

Comment: @CodeWhiz updated my answer. Didn't know you wanted it to be horizontally centered.

Comment: Thanks. You made my day.

Comment: @TriForce there isn't a high percentage in the overall userbase on the internet though. It's < 3%. That is not a "high percentage".

Answer (score 0):

Is it this that you want [sample form](https://jsfiddle.net/marco321/4r6r8vcw/1/)?

CSS

```
 .inputHolder {
  border: 1px solid #FFF;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.input {
  margin-top: 150px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  /* font-size: 1.2em; */
  padding: 0 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.input:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.goBtn {
  height: 52px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="inputHolder">
  <input type="text" class="input">
  <input type="submit" value="Go" class="goBtn">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to do this?

https://jsfiddle.net/pm3kpgL7/1/

If you want `vertical-align` elements, that property need to be placed to that element, not to his parent, so i just moved the vertical align to the inputs and it works using `vertical-align: sub`

```
.inputHolder{
  border:1px solid #FFF;
  text-align:center;
}
.input{
    margin-top:150px;
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    border:1px solid black;
    font-size:1.2em;
    padding:5px;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:sub;
}
.input:focus{
    outline:0;
}
.goBtn{
    height:50px;
    width:200px;
    border:1px solid black;
    display:inline-block;
}
```